# how to write a recursive function for delete nested folder

Tags: c#, linq

I have got a task to delete the hierarchy of folders. When i am deleting a folder, the respective sub folders should be deleted.

```
public ActionResult DeleteLabel(int id)
        {
            var query = dbPanAgroDMSContext.LabelMaster.Where(x => x.ParentLabelId == id).ToList();
            foreach(var item in query)
            {
                var query1 = dbPanAgroDMSContext.LabelMaster.Where(x => x.ParentLabelId == item.LabelId).ToList();
                dbPanAgroDMSContext.LabelMaster.Remove(item);
                foreach (var i in query1)
                {
                    dbPanAgroDMSContext.LabelMaster.Remove(i);
                }
            }
            LabelMaster label = dbPanAgroDMSContext.LabelMaster.Find(id);
            dbPanAgroDMSContext.LabelMaster.Remove(label);
            dbPanAgroDMSContext.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { Result = "OK" });
        }
```

Instead of using repeated for loops I want to do it in a single block of code.Please help me to create a linq query?

Comment: Is it mandatory to use LINQ for the recursion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public ActionResult DeleteLabel(int id)
        {
            Delete(id);
            dbPanAgroDMSContext.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { Result = "OK" });
        }
private void Delete(int id)
{
      //For given id get all child ones first            
          var query = dbPanAgroDMSContext.LabelMaster.Where(x => x.ParentLabelId == id).ToList();
            foreach(var item in query)
            {
                     //for each child ,delet its' childs by calling recursively
                    Delete(item.Id);
            }
            LabelMaster label = dbPanAgroDMSContext.LabelMaster.Find(id);
            dbPanAgroDMSContext.LabelMaster.Remove(label);
}
```